# Creating Web Service for Mobile Apps

Tags: java, android, ios, web-services

I'm trying to create a webservice to be consumed by mobile apps. I started using Eclipse to create it but when I got to the point of publishing it on the server, I created a .war file and uploaded it through cpanel. Howeever, I read that most servers don't support java. I can't seem to access my webservice and at this point I'm wondering if it would be a better option to start from scratch. I'm very lost and I really need help.

Is there a way to export java webservices so it's easier to upload through cpanel and how do you publish it?

What is the best program/language to create webservices that can be uploaded through cpanel?

Comment: To create and publish a webservice to be accessed through mobile devices.

Comment: you mean json parsing?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna publish a java web service I would recommend you to have a look at Openshift you can start for free and upgrade as you need. If you wanna start from scratch again, have a look at nodejs. I have no experience with node, so I cant give you much information on it, but I know that openshift has a free plan for node as well

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not quite what i'm asking. At this point I think java is not the best option for a web service as it is not supported by the server I'm using. If you have experience creating Web Services, what languages and platforms have you used? Have you published said web services through cpanel?

Comment: As I said, nodejs may be a good option. If you want to keep using the same server, I guess you should search for what languages you server supports

Answer (score 0):

Cpanel supports Java webservers so the fact that you cannot access your webserver might not be Cpanels fault. Also, there is no way to decide what is the 'best language' without knowing what you want to do with your webserver.

Please refer to the Cpanel documentation: [how to deploy Java applications](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Deploy+Java+Applications).